# C# Sending an email using a list for addresses

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, smtp

just had a quick question for you. I made a small application some-time ago which ends off by sending out an email to 4 recipients. However, I hard-coded the addresses. Going back to change things, I'd like to put the addresses in a .csv file and I will just read it in. This way, I can edit the .csv to control the email addresses.

I am just unsure on how you set up the recipients in the code. Obviously the variable name for the MailAddress has to be different, so I don't really know how to set up the loop, or what the proper way to do it would be.

Below is my code that I used, and commented out is my new code which reads in all of the email addresses from the file into a list. Can you point me in the right direction of how I'd go from there to send the email to all of the addresses in the list?

Thank you,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ReportEdit
{
    class sendEmail
    {
        public static void SendMyMail()
        {


           /* !!NEW!! READING IN THE .CSV TO GET LIST OF ADDRESSES. Below comment is old 

            List<string> addyList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Properties.Settings.Default.AddyList))
            {
                addyList.Add(line);
            }
            */

            SmtpClient companySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtprelay.company.com");

            companySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ActiveBatchRunReport@company.com", "ActiveBatchRunReport");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("GrpDstISOne@company.com", "DstOne");
            MailAddress Recipient1 = new MailAddress("Bill@company.com", "Bill");
            MailAddress Recipient2 = new MailAddress("Tom@company.com", "Tom");
            MailAddress Recipient3 = new MailAddress("Gena@company.com", "Gena");
            MailAddress Recipient4 = new MailAddress("Clifford@company.com", "Clifford");
            MailAddress ccKate = new MailAddress("Kate@company.com", "Kate");


            MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

            myMail.To.Add(Recipient1);
            myMail.To.Add(Recipient2);
            myMail.To.Add(Recipient3);
            myMail.To.Add(Recipient4);

            myMail.CC.Add(ccKate);

            myMail.Subject = "Daily Job Runs";
            myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            myMail.Body = "Attached you will find an Excel spreadsheet" +
            "Total Job counts are listed at the bottom.";

            myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            myMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"PathToAttachment"));

            companySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

/* !!NEW!! READING IN THE .CSV TO GET LIST OF ADDRESSES. Below comment is old */

```
        List<string> addyList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Properties.Settings.Default.AddyList))
        {
            addyList.Add(line);
            // to add Name, you need to store emailAddress and name in  certain way so that you can parse Name out of the line in here
        }

        SmtpClient companySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtprelay.company.com");

        companySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ActiveBatchRunReport@company.com", "ActiveBatchRunReport");

        foreach(string address in addyList)
        {
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(address);
            myMail.To.Add(to)
        }

        MailAddress ccKate = new MailAddress("Kate@company.com", "Kate");
        MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

        myMail.CC.Add(ccKate);

        myMail.Subject = "Daily Job Runs";
        myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        myMail.Body = "Attached you will find an Excel spreadsheet" +
        "Total Job counts are listed at the bottom.";

        myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        myMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"PathToAttachment"));

        companySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
```

Comment: This worked (I'm sure the other responses would have to)! So Thank you! I did have to change one line. I needed to make the declaration of "MailMessage myMail" to a 0 argument declaration up above and then manually assign the to and from properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make `addyList` a Dictionary rather than a List.  That will let you store both the email and the name, as you seem to be using both in your hardcoded version.  Assuming you do that, and successfully parse your CSV (which it looks like you aren't quite there yet), the following should do the trick if you replace the similar hardcoded calls in your code with it:

```
foreach (var kvp in addyList) {
    myMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

This loop assumes you are using the email address as the key and the name as the value in your dictionary.  If you swap it, just swap the .Key and .Value usages.

Also, CSV may be overkill for your purposes if app.config or web.config settings would work instead.  I recommend you look into that as an option.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can take the contents of your CSV file. Using that list you can then add them to the 'To' property of the mail message object.

```
        List<string> addyList = new List<string>();

        //populate string list from csv file

        MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        //populate this
        myMail.From = new MailAddress("ActiveBatchRunReport@company.com", "ActiveBatchRunReport");
        myMail.To.Add(string.Join(";", addyList));
```

If you need assistance on the csv file parsing please let me know.